# How to ensure two referenced foreign key tables have the same foreign key to another table?

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

Let's say I want to model matrices with different shapes and content in a relational database (in my case PostgreSQL). We can store multiple different matrices. Each matrix has a number of rows and columns that each may have some properties (e.g. name, position...). We can store value entries in each cell (row + column combination) of a matrix.

So we have a hierarchical design with 1:n relations from top to bottom and Row + Column as siblings which are both referenced by an Entry.

[image]

The Row and Column tables will both have a `matrixId` foreign key. The Entry table will have `rowId` and `columnId` as foreign keys.

**However, without further measure, it would be possible to create an Entry that references a Row and a Column that belong to different matrices.**

**What's the best practice to ensure an Entry always references a row and column with the same `matrixId`?**

I guess, we would probably also need a `matrixId` field in the Entry although this would introduce some kind of redundancy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand graphics and fuzzy text. Please present your model as DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, include `matrixid` in `entry` and in a (not necessarily primary)^1 key in `row` and `column` along with `rowid` or `columnid`, respectively and reference that in `entry`.

And as a side note: It's spelled "PostgreSQL". "postGreSQL" really hurts...

^1: Though it would make some sense that `rowid` or `columnid` are the ordinals of the row or column in the matrix which would make `(matrixid, rowid)` or `(matrixid, columnid)` a good candidate for a primary key.